# Is there a limit to the radius of a geofence in Android?

Tags: android, android-geofence

I develop an application that uses the Android Geofence API. Now I have the problem that, when the radius of the geofence is as large as 10 kilometers, it does not work, but when it is as small as 10 meters, then it works.

In the documentation, Google does not say much about the radius:

[Android Sample](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

[Geofence API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html)

[Geofence Builder API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder.html)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radius determines how large or small the circle is that is drawn around the geopoint.  There is not a maximum limit for the size of the radius, however what I have found is that the entry or exit off a fence requires triggering to happen, so with larger (10 km) maybe you're not triggering the entry or exit.

You mention that 10 meters works, have you tried 100?  1000?  I would test with increasing size and make sure you're logging your information as you test so you can determine if you are actually triggering the fence.

Comment: 10 meters is really work ? what is the exact minimum radius determine ?

Comment: 10 meters not working for me, Is there any minimum radius limit ?